# remotewebdriver - how to get logs from node

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

I am running tests using the selenium grid and remote web driver (Using testNG).
The nodes run on VMWare.

How can I get during the run the log that appear on the node ?
I create new driver per class so I want the log to be saved for each class.

How it can be done ?

I want also to record in video the run in the vmware.
Is it possible to record the vmware when the screen is not open?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of logs you want? the test failures, pass etc..? And, if you have a log why you want to record the tests as well?

Comment: I have the log from my tests.I want to add to log file I create for each test class the logs from the node.

Comment: The target is to make better debug in case there are failures. For this video recording can help also where I can show it to the engineer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a partial answer of your question. We have done some extensive research on how to handle selenium log. So far came out that [Log4j](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm) is one of the best options to use. Its allows you to log your result in different levels. Such as 'Fatal','Debug','Info' etc and different targets such as 'database, txt and console'. `With a simple try catch`  wrapper you can simply log every bit of of information you may want from each test.

Comment: But how do you get the logs from the selenium that runs on the node ?